# procfs and youtube flash video

Tags: linux, process, youtube, flash-player

Up until recently (about 3 months ago), ALL open flash videos had deleted file handles in the procfs virtual folder for the flash plugin, I could see them thus:

```
ps x|grep flash
cd /proc/#PROCESS#/fd
ls -l

cp #FILE# ~/
```

This still works for the vast majority of flash video, but some YouTube videos no longer keep this open file handle.

My questions are:

A) Why not?
B) Where are these files now stored?
C) How can I get this file

Yes I know I could probably get a browser plugin, it just annoys me that they are hiding these files so I want to keep doing it the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a new method...

But... if you're trying to download the videos from youtube, why not try the '**youtube-dl**' program?  Looks like there's even a few other similarly named downloaders for *nicovideo* and *metacafe*.

I use youtube-dl myself quite often and it downloads the highest quality videos possible for each requested video... all through a few command like options.

Comment: I like to know where flash is storing the files :)